# Add Today's Date to Cronjob URL

Tags: cron

I'm trying to add today's date to my cronjob that's running. Though the date isn't currently appending. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 "https://www.exampleurl.com?date=`date +\%y\%m\%d`"
```

Comment: why not chron into a shell script then building the url in there?

Comment: Thought it'd be simple to just create it in cron :)